# I want to remove the common elements in two arrays using PHP

Tags: php

I tried the following code and it should be working, but not getting the required result. What's wrong with the code?  I have two arrays and I want to remove the common elements in both arrays so I wore the following code.

```
<?php

 $aMgaMembersList= array (
  0 => '9194962',
  1 => '9197448',
  2 => '9174039',
  3 => '9199473',
  4 => '9175598',
  5 => '9197474',
  6 => '9195444',
  7 => '9195268',
  8 => '9189438',
  9 => '9175103',
  10 => '9199619',
  11 => '9195267',
  12 => '9194463',
  13 => '9196333',
  14 => '9197471',
  15 => '9198479',
  16 => '9197472',
  17 => '9185479',
  18 => '9197452',
  19 => '9197442',
  20 => '9180861',
  21 => '9194950',
  22 => '9198464',
  23 => '9199613',
  24 => '9175939',
  25 => '9195442',
  26 => '9190203',
  27 => '9199613',
)  ;

$aRocketMembersList = array (
  0 => '9174039',
  1 => '9175103',
  2 => '9175598',
  3 => '9175939',
  4 => '9180861',
  5 => '9185479',
  6 => '9189438',
  7 => '9190203',
  8 => '9194463',
  9 => '9194950',
  10 => '9194962',
  11 => '9195267',
  12 => '9195268',
  13 => '9195442',
  14 => '9195444',
  15 => '9196333',
  16 => '9197442',
  17 => '9197448',
  18 => '9197452',
  19 => '9197471',
  20 => '9197472',
  21 => '9197474',
  22 => '9198464',
  23 => '9198479',
  24 => '9199473',
  25 => '9199613',
  26 => '9199619',
  27 => 'arun',
)  ;



 if (is_array($aRocketMembersList)) {
            foreach ($aRocketMembersList as $rocketUsername) {
                if (in_array($rocketUsername, $aMgaMembersList)) {
                   
                    unset($aMgaMembersList[array_search($rocketUsername, $aMgaMembersList)]);
                    unset($aRocketMembersList[array_search($rocketUsername, $aRocketMembersList)]);
                }
            }
        }

print_r($aRocketMembersList);
print_r($aMgaMembersList);
```

The out put is

```
Array
(
    [27] => arun
)
Array
(
    [27] => 9199613
)
```

The element `9199613` shouldn't be there. Why it's happening? I ran the code in a different environment and the result is same.

Comment: Consult the manual first and you'll find things like [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). Combine that with [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and you have a very small solution.

Comment: The reason it occurs is `9199613` is in the `$aMgaMembersList` array twice. And [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will return the first key as a result, in this case `23`, which you removed with `unset()` but do not reiterate over the `$aRocketMembersList ` array.  To find multiple keys with a specific value, use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional `search_value` parameter instead. Alternative use [`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicated values

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `different` function that works regardless of the order of Arrays:

```
<?php
function different($array1, $array2){
  $m = array_merge($array1, $array2); $x = array_intersect($array1, $array2); $a = array_diff($m, $x); $b = array_diff($x, $m); $a = array_merge($a, $b);
  $r = [];
  foreach($a as $v){
    $o = new StdClass; $k = array_search($v, $array1);
    if($k === false)$k = array_search($v, $array2);
    $o->$k = [$array1[$k], $array2[$k]]; $r[] = $o;
  }
  return $r;
}
$aMgaMembersList = [
  0 => '9194962',
  1 => '9197448',
  2 => '9174039',
  3 => '9199473',
  4 => '9175598',
  5 => '9197474',
  6 => '9195444',
  7 => '9195268',
  8 => '9189438',
  9 => '9175103',
  10 => '9199619',
  11 => '9195267',
  12 => '9194463',
  13 => '9196333',
  14 => '9197471',
  15 => '9198479',
  16 => '9197472',
  17 => '9185479',
  18 => '9197452',
  19 => '9197442',
  20 => '9180861',
  21 => '9194950',
  22 => '9198464',
  23 => '9199613',
  24 => '9175939',
  25 => '9195442',
  26 => '9190203',
  27 => '9199613'
];
$aRocketMembersList = [
  0 => '9174039',
  1 => '9175103',
  2 => '9175598',
  3 => '9175939',
  4 => '9180861',
  5 => '9185479',
  6 => '9189438',
  7 => '9190203',
  8 => '9194463',
  9 => '9194950',
  10 => '9194962',
  11 => '9195267',
  12 => '9195268',
  13 => '9195442',
  14 => '9195444',
  15 => '9196333',
  16 => '9197442',
  17 => '9197448',
  18 => '9197452',
  19 => '9197471',
  20 => '9197472',
  21 => '9197474',
  22 => '9198464',
  23 => '9198479',
  24 => '9199473',
  25 => '9199613',
  26 => '9199619',
  27 => 'arun'
];
$diffArray = different($aMgaMembersList, $aRocketMembersList);
$test = json_encode($diffArray);
?>
```

Comment: Might steal this for my collection of random php functions

Comment: @TCooper, that's what Stack Overflow is for. Well, it's not stealing if it's on this site anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp1 = array_diff($aMgaMembersList,$aRocketMembersList);
$tmp2 = array_diff($aRocketMembersList,$aMgaMembersList);
$final = array_unqiue(array_merge($tmp1, $tmp2));
unset($tmp1);unset($tmp2);//and maybe original arrays?
```

There are probably better solutions, but that should work for you. If you had associative arrays instead of numeric values you could exclude `array_unqiue`

EDIT:
I originally assumed you wanted the results in one array, if that's unnecessary just use the array_diff function twice, and you can maintain your original array names as desired. Again there are probably better solutions (more memory/processor efficient), but in *most* practical cases this will be fine. If you're working with extremely large data sets... do more research ;)

Comment: just as an FYI, you can chain variables [`unset($tmp1, $tmp2);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Comment: @fyrye I tend to write things extremely verbose, it was hard for me not to put those on separate lines lol, it just looked cleaner in this case. Is there a difference in memory I should be aware of? That'd be worth changing habits for.

Comment: Yes, each call to `unset` does have a performance hit, albeit very minor.

Comment: @fyrye most everything is minor until you're iterating over a million rows. Thanks for the tip.